# Import Sharepoint Document Library using SSIS

Tags: sharepoint, ssis

We need to import SharePoint Document Library (which could be holding multiple document in multiple formats) to a destination folder (on different server) using SSIS.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/28adf47e-c26b-41ce-a3fe-d7546219b2b8

Comment: Why do you want to use SSIS for this? Why not write a small application to do it? Also, which version of SharePoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are open source SSIS adapters available for SharePoint. You can use these.

http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/
http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17652

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a script task in ssis and use c# to extract files from SharePoint Library to a local folder. Make sure the SharePoint url only contains siteurl/Library/Folder/File (no special characters). Below copies one file but can be modified to copy multiple files. Good luck.

```
using System.net;


public void main ()
{
WebClient Client = new WebClient();
Client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
Client.DownloadFile("yourSharePointurl/File.ext", 
@"YourLocalFolder/File.ext");
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Comment: I tired this and it gives an error: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

Comment: Same error for me as well `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation` - any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Change this "using System.net;" to using "System.Net;"

My compilation error got fixed