# Is it possible to pull data from an excel sheet stored on sharepoint online?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, ssis, sharepoint-online

I have SSIS available to me.  I currently have it configured to pull using oData connector. I'm hoping to be able to pull data stored on a sheet in SharePoint online. If I have to write a c# script I can do that as well. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you seen this thread regarding Excel and SSIS? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45571274/6445723

It suggests fetching the excel file from SharePoint and afterwards loading each separately as a data source.

Alternatively if using SSIS is not a must, then you can look into using the Excel Graph REST API (Do not confuse this with the Excel Services REST API that has been available since SharePoint 2010 and is only relevant for on-premises deployments). Here is a link about this API: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/examples/excel-workbook-integration

The advantage of the latter approach is that does not require a specific programming language: anything that you know well and can make a REST call will pretty much do.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'm not dealing with On-Prem instances so I'm assuming the later won't work. I appreciate pointing me in the write direction!

Comment: Glad to help - the latter option will work in SP Online - the Excel Graph REST API (its all in the name), I just pointed out that besides the Graph API which you can use (new) there was an older API called Excel Services REST API which did pretty much the same but was only available on-prem.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!