# Sharepoint and Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint list where every item has an attachment in .xlsx format.Is it possible to read the content of the attachments and then create a table in Sql.

example, if there are 10 items with 10 attachments , then it should create 10 tables with the contents from the attachment..

any possibilities ?

Comment: Why do that at all? What are you trying to do and why do you think that copying anything to SQL Server is the solution? Besides *attachments* are *files* not rows. The question doesn't make sense as is. You describe what you have but not what you want to do.

Comment: ODATA and CSOM can get you list items and attachments. Libraries like EPPlus or even an OpenXmlReader can read that data. What do you want to do with it though? Each file can have completely different contents, multiple sheets, multiple ranges per sheet

Comment: You can look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555620/ssis-download-and-load-excel-from-sharepoint-to-sql-database
OR
Cozyroc (which is out of bizz) was a 3rd party component you can use to dl sharepoint excel.
Either way if its a 1 time solution you can go proposed route in url above to just dl the excel locally and then ETL into sql tables. But if its a on-going process you may need a solidified solution.