# Using SSIS to pull a JSON from Sharepoint and importing into Oracle

Tags: c#, json, sharepoint, import, ssis

I'm trying to pull a JSON file from sharepoint and importing it into Oracle. When I put the JSON file in my C Drive and use this file path C:\json\jsonfile.json it loads perfectly. When I switch to my Sharepoint path it does not upload.

Here is the script I am using. Any ideas on how to get it to pull from sharepoint? Works perfectly when the file is on my c drive but not when I use my sharepoint file path.

```
String jsonFileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"\\sharepoint.site.gov\sites\pagename\folder\jsonfilen.json");
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    js.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
    List<Data> datas = js.Deserialize<List<Data>>(jsonFileContent);
    foreach(Data data in datas)
```

Here is the error message that I get:

"A Device attached to the system is not functioning."

> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, >Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.File.ReadAllText(String path)
>      at ScriptMain.CreateNewOutputRows()
>      at UserComponent.PrimeOutput(Int32 Outputs, Int32[] OutputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] Buffers, OutputNameMap OutputMap)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.PrimeOutput(Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)

Comment: Would it make more sense to use the SharePoint API to retrieve the file?

Comment: I'm creating an SSIS package that will load multiple files. I have csv, excel, and this JSON file all coming from a sharepoint site

Comment: Is this related? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45553754/3608792